# Splitting bytes into "16 bit words"

Tags: python, byte, checksum, unsigned-integer

I have the following task:
Write a function `split(data: bytes) -> List[int]` that splits the input
from data into 16 bit long segments, each represented as an
unsigned integer. These integers should use big-endian byte order (so we
are able to test your solution).

You can assume that the length of the data is a multiple of 2 bytes
(16 bit).

I also have this current solution:

```
def split(data: bytes):
    counter = 0 # counter to always get two bytes
    l = []
    for i in data:
        if counter == 0: # first byte
            num1 = hex(i)
            counter += 1
        else:
            num2 = hex(i) # second byte
            if num2 == "0x0": # if it is 0 append another 0 (i dont know why it has to 
                num2 += "0"  # be like this, it is required in onther code which expects
            num1 += num2[2:]    # unsigned ints, i guess it has something to do with this
            l.append(int(num1, base = 16))
            counter = 0
    return l
```

for the test

```
data = b'Sphinx of Black Quartz,  Judge my Vow!'

pretty_print(split(data))
```

(pretty_print is not visible for me) it produces the correct output:

```
The 16-bit words are:
0x5370
0x6869
0x6e78
0x206f
0x6620
0x426c
0x6163
0x6b20
0x5175
0x6172
0x747a
0x2c20
0x204a
0x7564
0x6765
0x206d
0x7920
0x566f
0x7721
```

Unfortunate there are some hidden test and my code fails one of them.
Can anyone see what might cause problems?
[Picture of the testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1D9Z.png)

Comment: what are the tests that you have developed?

Comment: *pretty_print is not visible for me* ... that is because it's called `pprint.pprint()` and your code needs to import it first.

Comment: @Andrew what do you mean, I have this test stated in the question. I have another similar test if seeing that might help

Comment: @BoarGules it is only used in the automated testing,, as i said, the test in my question ist correct, the code produces the output as expectet

Comment: @BoarGules i hope the added picture explains what i mean

Comment: @BoarGules I think they mean that the function is defined by whatever website they are using and they cannot see the implementation. But the function still works either way.

Comment: @Lecdi yes exactly

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your output. No idea what the website is complaining about. Your code     may be a bit unstylish but it's workmanlike and does the job correctly.

Comment: There is no `t` defined when you write `num1 += t[2:]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i just forgot to change it as I changed it from t to num2 when i asked it here